# Send command to android phone via Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: php, android, google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging

I want to make a connection between chrome and android via Google Cloud Messaging.
Is there any way to open a certain app from chrome (I want to code it in PHP) on the android phone? or is there any alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: can you give a direct example of what you want to do ? Do you want that a weblink opens an android app ?

Comment: I want to make a Chrome Extension that sends the link that the user is on (For example YouTube) and that the phone receives a command like Intent blabla packagemanager com.google.chrome, and that it opens chrome on the phone with that specific link

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Web Push API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en) in Chrome on mobile to have the connection between GCM and the Chrome browser on the mobile device.

Now create an extension that connects the user on the desktop to the registration ID on the mobile device and call GCM as normal.

Comment: I dont wan to use Push Messages.

Comment: Push messaging is the same as Google Cloud Messaging